# What is the functional difference between these two definitions?

Tags: java

```java
// in PingPongMessage.java
public class PingPong {
  
  public static final class Ping { } 

} 

// in PingActor.java
public class PingActor extends AbstractBehavior<PingPong.Ping> {

    public static Behavior<PingPong.Ping> create() {
        return Behaviors.setup(context -> new PingActor(context));
    }

    private PingActor(ActorContext<PingPong.Ping> context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive<PingPong.Ping> createReceive() {
        return newReceiveBuilder().onMessage(PingPong.Ping.class, this::onPingMsg).build();
    }

    private Behavior<PingPong.Ping> onPingMsg() {
        System.out.println("Ping!");
        return this;
    }

}
```

vs.

```java
// in PingActor.java

public class PingActor extends AbstractBehavior<PingActor.Ping>{

    public static final class Ping {

    }

    public static Behavior<Ping> create() {
        return Behaviors.setup(context -> new PingActor(context));
    }

    private PingActor(ActorContext<Ping> context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive<Ping> createReceive() {
        return newReceiveBuilder()
                .onMessage(Ping.class, this::onPingMessage).build();
    }

    private Behavior<Ping> onPingMessage(Ping message){
        System.out.println("Ping!");
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand the relationship between `Ping` and `PingActor` in both the cases. In my opinion both are doing the same thing, but in one case `PingPong.Ping` is defined inside `PingActor` and in the other case `PingPong` is another class outside of it. Obviously they are not the same because the second example seems to compile, but the first does not.

The compiler error is -
`Inferred type 'M' for type parameter 'M' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.lightbend.akka.sample.PingPong.Ping` seen in `Receive<PingPong.Ping> createReceive()`

Comment: **"but the first does not."** - And the compile error is .... ?

Comment: Please add more details on the compilation error you are getting.

Comment: updated the post with erorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a public class "PingPong" inside PingPongMessage.java
They don't match

Comment: you mean the file has to be PingPong.java?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 Yes the file name must be the same as the `public class <name>` declaration. There's some exceptions like if you make a subclass and just do "class <name>" but for the primary class of the file it needs to match.